# Drag view from RecyclerView Adapter to view inside container Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` inside `Fragment` and i want to Drag row from this `Recycler` `Adapter` and drop it into a view in the container `Fragment` - "The `Recycler` and the `View` inside the same fragment, I tried a lot of codes from stack and youtube, I used this code to achieve the drag and drop but it works only in the views out side the adapter only.

```
private class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    RowNewsRecylcerHolder holder;



    public ChoiceTouchListener(RowNewsRecylcerHolder holder) {
        this.holder = holder;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.rightMargin;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = 250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = 250;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


                break;


        }
        holder.getRowCardViewContent().invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: @CommonsWare can you post an example of code please? because I tried it but unable to drag item outside RecyclerView size.

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DragDrop/Simple -- note that you need 1+ videos on the test device or emulator, as the sample app queries `MediaStore` for available videos and shows those in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Very thank you . Now,I want to action the dragged item when I release my hand. Because I want to make action when the dragged item touch certain button.Can you help me?